# How to extract a single pattern present in a string more than once in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following data

```
Description
4 GB+ 2 GB Night 3G/2G Data
Unlimited Local & STD Calls + 500 MB 3G/2G Data (T&C apply)
9GB + 8GB night data+ 6GB next night data
8 GB data 4G
```

What I want is to extract amount of data(4GB etc) and merge them in a single column

```
df2=df['Description'].str.extract('([0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?\s?GB|[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?\s?MB)')
```

I have used pandas function `extractall()` too but both `extract`and `extractall()`giving me result like this

```
0     1    2
4GB   Nan  Nan     #2 gb is missing
500MB Nan  Nan   
9GB   Nan  Nan     # 8gb 6 gb is missing
8Gb   Nan  Nan
```

Where i am wrong? 
Also when combining the rows with `df.fillna(' ')`i am getting an output like this

```
     0 
    4GB,2GB, 
    500MB, , 
    9GB,8GB,6GB
    8GB, ,
```

though what i want is

```
0
4GB,2GB
500MB
9GB,8GB,6GB
8GB
```

I dont want spaces.Is there any way in pandas to get the data in the above format? I am a beginner in python,don't know how to achieve this.If there is another way please mention.

EDIT:

this the full code:

```
df2=df['Description'].str.extractall('([0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?\s?GB|[0-     9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?\s?MB)')
#print df2
df2[1].fillna("",inplace=True);
df2[2].fillna("",inplace=True)
print df2
df3=df2[0]+','+df2[1]+','+df2[2];
print df3
```

Comment: Why don't you do .fillna("") ?

Comment: Also can you profide a sample code that generate your dataframe ?

Comment: even with .fillna('') the commas with white spaces are coming

Comment: Can't you just use .dropna(how='all',axis=0) ?

Comment: It is not working.Nan are coming.

Comment: Okay, can you tell me what is the output and format ? Do you want just the serie, a new dataframe with only thoses value, a list ?

Comment: I want a series with the desired output i have shown above before edit

Comment: ok, didn't get that you wanted them by line, sorry !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using extractall should work like below:

```
df.Description.str\
  .extractall('(\d*\s?[GM]B)').groupby(level=0)\
  .apply(lambda x: ','.join(x[0])\
  .replace(' ',''))
Out[75]: 
0        4GB,2GB
1          500MB
2    9GB,8GB,6GB
3            8GB
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks , you solved my problem,but can you explain whats inside .apply doing?

Comment: inside apply, it's just join those fields(4GB, 2GB etc) together and separated them by ','

Answer (score 1):

```
df2=df['Description'].str.extractall('(\d*\.\d+|\d+\s?GB|\d*\.\d+|\d+\s?MB)').reset_index()
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df2, index='level_0', columns="match", values=0, aggfunc='last').reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df2.apply(lambda row: ','.join(row.dropna()), axis=1)
```

Try this code for your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data as columns like this

```
df2=df['Description'].str.extractall('([0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?\s?GB|[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?\s?MB)')
df2.reset_index().groupby('match')[0].apply(lambda x: "{%s}" % ', '.join(x)).apply(lambda x:x.replace(" ",""))
```

output :

```
match
0    {4GB,500MB,9GB,8GB}
1              {2GB,8GB}
2                  {6GB}
Name: 0, dtype: object
```